# How To Fetch all Selected Permissions of Group model in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to create custom groups and permissions on Django, but I am facing some problem.
how can I fetch all selected permissions on the chosen group??

**`{{users_list.permissions}}`**

Answer (score 0):

The group:permissions relationship is many to many so for a given `group` you should be able to do `group.permissions_set.all()`